# Visual Basic HowTo: Retrieve Data from .mdf

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

What am I doing wrong? I have been going at this for a while now... I surrender.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using sqlCon = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\gadgetDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True")

        Dim Id As Integer = 2
        'With the use of ID, it will get the appName or Application Display Name
        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim sqlText = "SELECT appName " & _
                      "FROM appTable " & _
                      "WHERE Id = @sqlID"
        Dim sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlText, sqlCon)
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlID", Id)
        'sqlCmd.ToString()
        sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar() 'I had these in there before I copied the code over
        sqlCon.Close()
        Label3.Text = sqlText 'For testing or confirmation it went correctly...

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: It has been accepted and upvoted. I apologize @MitchWheat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call

```
string apName = sqlCmd.ExecuteScaler();
```

and retrieve the result.

If a resultset (multiple results) is expected, then call `reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()`  and loop through the results.

Comment: I had it in there, but when I brought the code over I took it our by accident... It is still returning the SELECT statement as the label text instead of the appName